# Can I queue.get() for an arbitrary time in a python thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a python script that I use interactively for requesting reports, querying data, and so on. Some functions may also produce other data I must use for performance reporting, but it's not immediately relevant so I thought of using a Thread and a queue to handle them without affecting performance. the code is basically like this:

```py
# THE CODE HANDLING THE PERFORMANCE REPORTING
q_stats = LifoQueue()
consume_queue = True
def handle_queue():
    # get element from queue
    # save it to gdrive
    try:
        while consume_queue:
            q_stat = q_stats.get()
            # ... transform data, upload, and so on...
    except Exception as e:
        logger.warning("Exception while handling the queue:")
    logger.debug("Queue handler closed")
thread_qstat = threading.Thread( target=handle_queue )
thread_qstat.start()
```

The main script will do its thing and occasionally `q_stats.put(stuff)` on my last request.
I keep this script open for a large part of my day, using it only when I need it. Which means somewhere a thread is stuck on `.get()` for literal hours.
I know it may sound silly, but is it "bad" for some reasons? Could the `get()` fail even if I didn't give it a time limit? Or will it give me bad performances in some cases? Should I use some events instead?